# StateParams are empty on page refresh using the ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use angular's ui-router and nested routes in a project and I'm faced by the problem that everything works like a charm when I use links (ui-sref) to navigate to the user's detail page with the userId as part of the url. When I refresh the page, state params are missing.

So I've taken a look at the angular demo: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1/item/b and couldn't reproduce this behaviour, however nested states are not part of this demo in contrast to my application.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('base', {
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('home', {
      parent: 'base',
      url: '/',
      views: {
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'app/index/index.view.html',
          controller: 'IndexController',
          controllerAs: 'home'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('users', {
      url: '/users',
      parent: 'base',
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('users.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'app/users/users.list.html',
          controller: 'UsersController',
          controllerAs: 'users'
        }
      },
      permissions: {
        authorizedRoles: UserRoles.ALL_ROLES
      }
    })
    .state('users.details', {
      url: '/:userId/details',
      views: {
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'app/users/user.details.html',
          controller: 'UserDetailsController',
          controllerAs: 'userDetails'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        logSomeParams: ['$stateParams', '$state', function ($stateParams, $state) {
          console.log($stateParams);
          console.log(this);
          console.log($state);
        }]
      }
    })
```

When refreshing the page the url immediately changes to http://localhost:3000/#/users//details and console output (resolve function) shows that params are missing.

html5Mode (LocationProvider) is not enabled. I already found "solutions" like redirecting back to the list if the the userId is missing on page refresh, but I just can't believe that there isn't a better way to solve this.

This is how I linked the details page in the overview (and it is working):

```
  <div class="panel-body" ui-sref="users.details({userId: user.siloUserId})">
```

Answer (score 2):

As expected, my problem had nothing to do with the `ui-router`. The `URLMatcher` works as expected, even if you refresh the page (everything else would have been a huge dissapointment).

However, I have a `$stateChangeStart` listener which checks if the `SAML` authentication session (cookie) is still valid and waits for the result.

```
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(!authenticationService.isInitialized()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      authenticationService.getDeferred().then(() => {
        $state.go(toState);
      });
    } else {
      //check authorization
      if ( authenticationService.protectedState(toState) && !authenticationService.isAuthorized(toState.permissions.authorizedRoles)) {
        authenticationService.denyAccess();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
}
```

No idea how this could happen, but I forgot to pass the parameters to the `go` method of the `stateProvider`. So all I had to change was to add the params:

```
$state.go(toState, toParams);
```